# Rails: each for multiple and one object data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new in rails and need to clear one question:

for example my method return such data:

```
 #<Article ART_ID: 1151754, ART_ARTICLE_NR: "0 281 002 757", ART_SUP_ID: 30, ART_DES_ID: nil, ART_COMPLETE_DES_ID: 62395, ART_CTM: nil, ART_PACK_SELFSERVICE: 0, ART_MATERIAL_MARK: 0, ART_REPLACEMENT: 0, ART_ACCESSORY: 0, ART_BATCH_SIZE1: nil, ART_BATCH_SIZE2: nil, datetime_of_update: "2012-09-25 17:49:18">
```

or array, not only one object: how could use each func then?

for example:

```
articles = ArtLookup.search_strong_any_kind_without_brand(params[:article_nr].gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''))
      binding.pry
        if articles.present?
          articles.each do |a|
            @all_parts_result << 
            {
              analogue_manufacturer_name: a.supplier.SUP_BRAND,
              analogue_code: a.ART_ARTICLE_NR,
              delivery_time_min: '',
              delivery_time_max: '',
              min_quantity: '',
              product_name: a.art_name,
              quantity: '',
              price: '',
              distributor_id: '',
              link_to_tecdoc: a.ART_ID
            }
          end
        end
```

now i get errors like

```
 `undefined method `each' for `#<Article:0x007f6554701640>
```

i think it is becouse i have sometimes one object, sometimes 10, and sometime 0.

how is it beatifull and right to do in rails?

Comment: I think your `search_strong_any_kind_without_brand` method must be unusual. Why doesn't always return an array or active record collection regardless of the number of results?

Comment: @ptd here it is `http://pastebin.com/ZRzz2E7A` - what i do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `search_strong_any_kind_without_brand` method is looping through your articles based on the search condition. If the article matches then you are setting `@art_concret` to the match and then returning the match. However, you're not finding all matches, just the last one.

```
.
loop
  @art_concret = art
end
.
return @art_concret
```

If you set the `@art_concret` as an array and inject results into this instance variable, then you will have the resulting search in array form. However, keep in mind that this does kind of break the ActiveRecord ORM as you would be returning a simple array and not an ActiveRecord Relation array.

```
def self.search_strong_any_kind_without_brand(search)
    search_condition = search.upcase
    @art_concret = []
    @search = find(:all, :conditions => ['MATCH (ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', search_condition])
    @articles = Article.find(:all, :conditions => ["ART_ID in (?)", @search.map(&:ARL_ART_ID)])
    #binding.pry
    @articles.each do |art|
      if art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '') == search
        @art_concret << art
      end
    end    
    return @art_concret
  end
```

If you want to keep the code a bit cleaner then use `select` on your matching condition instead of looping through each article in `@articles`.

```
def self.search_strong_any_kind_without_brand(search)
    search_condition = search.upcase
    @search = find(:all, :conditions => ['MATCH (ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)', search_condition])
    @articles = Article.find(:all, :conditions => ["ART_ID in (?)", @search.map(&:ARL_ART_ID)])
    #binding.pry
    return @articles.select { |art| art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '') == search } 
  end
```

Unrelated: is there a reason why you're using instance variables in `search_strong_any_kind_without_brand`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right thing to do is to make sure your method always returns an array (or enumerable).

looking at the code you posted in to pastebin I would recommend you use [Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) in your method
for example you might be able to just return this:

```
@articles.select { |art| art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '') == search }
```

assuming @articles is an array or collection you will always get an array back, even if it is 0, or 1 element

Answer (score 0):

This answer would be a bit offtopic, but I would like to mention a [splat operator](https://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/01/16/the-splat-operator-in-ruby/):

```
[*val]
```

will produce array, consisting of either single `val` value whether it’s not an array, or the array itself whether `val` is an array:

```
▶ def array_or_single param
▷   [*param].reduce &:+  # HERE WE GO
▷ end  
=> :array_or_single
▶ array_or_single [1,2,3]
=> 6
▶ array_or_single 5
=> 5
```

That said, you code would work with this tiny improvement:

```
- articles.each do |a|
+ [*articles].each do |a|
```

Hope it gives a hint on how one might handle the data, coming from the 3rd party. As an answer to your particular question, please follow the advises in the other answers here.